# How to select filtered postgresql jsonb field with performance prioritization?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

A table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events_holder(
    id serial primary key,
    version int not null,
    data jsonb not null
);
```

Data field can be very very large (up to 100 Mb) and looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "name5",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 255,
      "name": "festival",
      "start_date": "2022-04-15",
      "end_date": "2023-04-15",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 654,
          "type": "text",
          "name": "importance",
          "value": "high"
        },
        {
          "id": 655,
          "type": "boolean",
          "name": "epic",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 256,
      "name": "discovery",
      "start_date": "2022-02-20",
      "end_date": "2022-02-22",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 711,
          "type": "text",
          "name": "importance",
          "value": "low"
        },
        {
          "id": 712,
          "type": "boolean",
          "name": "specificAttribute",
          "value": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to select data field by version, but filtered with extra condition: where events end_date > '2022-03-15'. And the output must look like this:

```json
{
  "id": 5,
  "name": "name5",
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 255,
      "name": "festival",
      "start_date": "2022-04-15",
      "end_date": "2023-04-15",
      "values": [
        {
          "id": 654,
          "type": "text",
          "name": "importance",
          "value": "high"
        },
        {
          "id": 655,
          "type": "boolean",
          "name": "epic",
          "value": "true"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do this with maximum performance? How should I index the data field?

My primary solution:

```sql
with cte as (
  select eh.id, eh.version, jsonb_agg(events) as filteredEvents from events_holder eh
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(eh.data #> '{events}') as events
  where version = 1 and (events ->> 'end_date')::timestamp >= '2022-03-15'::timestamp
  group by id, version
)
select jsonb_set(data, '{events}', cte.filteredEvents) from events_holder, cte 
where events_holder.id = cte.id;
```

But i don't think it's a good variant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a JSON path expression:

```
select eh.id, eh.version, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(data, 
                              '$.events[*] ? (@.end_date.datetime() >= "2022-03-15".datetime())')
from events_holder eh
where eh.version = 1
  and eh.data @? '$.events[*] ? (@.end_date.datetime() >= "2022-03-15".datetime())'
```

Given your example JSON, this returns:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 255,
        "name": "festival",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": 654,
                "name": "importance",
                "type": "text",
                "value": "high"
            },
            {
                "id": 655,
                "name": "epic",
                "type": "boolean",
                "value": "true"
            }
        ],
        "end_date": "2023-04-15",
        "start_date": "2022-04-15"
    }
]
```

Depending on your data distribution a GIN index on `data` or an index on `version` could help.

If you need to re-construct the whole JSON content but with just a filtered `events` array, you can do something like this:

```
select (data - 'events')||
        jsonb_build_object('events', jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.events[*] ? (@.end_date.datetime() >= "2022-03-15".datetime())'))
from events_holder eh
...
```

`(data - 'events')` removes the `events` key from the json. Then the the result of the JSON path query is appended back to that (partial) object.

Comment: thank u for your answer! I think "and eh.data @? '$.events[*] ? (@.end_date.datetime() >= "2022-03-15".datetime())'"  is redundant to get the desired filtered array. But is there a way to get hole object by version with such an array without calling jsonb_set function?
As for the index, btree index on version i already have, but i dont know the correct expression for gin index on data.

Comment: @Evangilit: well the WHERE clause is there in case an index is present. I don't understand what you mean with "get the whole object by version" - if you want the whole content of the `data column` then just select that column. My query returns the `events` array that match the "JSON condition". If you need the other keys from the `data` column, then just add them to the SELECT list: `data ->> 'id', data ->> 'name'`

Comment: yeah as you mentioned in your answer i need to reconstruct the whole JSON content but with just a filtered events array. Your query for this works. The last thing i need is to optimize this filtering. Is it possible somehow to do that using gin index? The data content which is needed to be filtered and reconstructed i get via indexed column version.